# else statement not working. only prints from the IF statement

Tags: c#

My program doesn't enter the else statement. When i type different number from 5. It's only printing the if statement how can I fix this ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;

namespace Question2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String ID = "5";
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student ID");
            Console.ReadLine();

            string answer = "TFTTFTFFTF";
            ID = "TTFFTFTTFT";
            int count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
            {
                if (answer[i] == ID[i])
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if (ID == "5")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This student mark is");
                Console.WriteLine(count);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error no student with this ID");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no way this code would go the true part of `if (ID == 5)`, If you are asking about `if (answer[i] == ID[i])` then this condition is true based on the values you provided in the code, Also it appears you want to get input from user for `ID`, you are not storing the value of `ReadLine` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Should it not instead be `if (count = 5)` instead of `if (ID == "5")`.  ID is *always* `TTFFTFTTFT`

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to do here. Do you want to print the number of exact answers given by the student or what else?

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the `ID` variable

```
ID = "TTFFTFTTFT";
```

If you want to receive the student id from the user, you should save it.
Use one variable for the StudentId and Another for the answers he filled.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Student ID");
String ID = Console.ReadLine();         

string answer = "TFTTFTFFTF";
string studentAnswers = "TTFFTFTTFT";

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
{
    if (answer[i] == studentAnswers[i])
    {
        count++;
    }
}

if (ID == "5")
{
    Console.WriteLine("This student mark is");
    Console.WriteLine(count);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("error no student with this ID");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Important remark:** Debugger is a **must use** tool, Use it!